# Extract the rows having all the column values greater than or equal to threshold

Tags: awk, sed

I have a .csv file and want to extract all the rows only if all the columns contain value >= 10

Example File

```
A,09,08,07,06 
B,10,11,13,17
C,19,09,20,08
D,25,11,10,10
```

Expected output

```
B,10,11,13,17
D,25,11,10,10
```

I have tried, but it is working only for 1 column

```
awk -F, '{if($2>=10)print $0}'
```

Comment: `grep` or `sed` in this case will involve writing regex filtering you number, which is not great thing to support or modify. For this exact case: `grep -E '^[A-Z]+(,[1-9][0-9]+)*$'` or `sed -zE 's/[^\n]*,0[0-9](,[^\n]*\n|\n|$)//g' test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this loop:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i<10)next;print}' data.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/(^|,)0+.?(,|$)/d' file
```

If a line contains a match for a zero or a single digit number beginning with leading zeroes, delete that line.